# Correct Ruby version, but can't init RNative project

Tags: ruby, react-native

```
✖ Installing Bundler
error Your RubyGems version (3.0.3.1) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6
```

```
❯ ruby --version


ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]
```

```
❯ which -a ruby
/Users/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Your issue is obviously a bit strange but have you tried updating ruby gems as mentioned (`gem update --system`) and installing the correct ruby version through rvm `rvm install 2.7.6` ?